# How to apply filter to .npz / .npy file?

Tags: python, numpy

I new to programming.

How do I call .npz/.npy file to apply my Sobel filter with below code. Its a 3x3 kernel. I have used below code for my 2D images but I have problem in applying this to my .npy/.npz file.

```
Gx = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [2.0, 0.0, -2.0], [1.0, 0.0, -1.0]])
Gy = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -2.0, -1.0]])
[rows, columns] = np.shape(grayscale_image) 
sobel_filtered_image = np.zeros(shape=(rows, columns))

for i in range(rows - 2):
    for j in range(columns - 2):
        gx = np.sum(np.multiply(Gx, grayscale_image[i:i + 3, j:j + 3]))  
        gy = np.sum(np.multiply(Gy, grayscale_image[i:i + 3, j:j + 3]))  
        sobel_filtered_image[i + 1, j + 1] = np.sqrt(gx ** 2 + gy ** 2)  

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax1, ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(121), fig2.add_subplot(122)
ax1.imshow(input_image)
ax2.imshow(sobel_filtered_image, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Check this to format your code so that its easier for others to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: use `np.load` to read the file, resulting in an array (or several from a .npz.)  You need to read more numpy basics.

Comment: I have successfully called my .npz file but still having problem to apply the filter. Where should I start?